# RewriteRule for the same file which is currently targeted

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a file like

```
www.domain.com/test.php
```

I want to write a rule that when ever this is called i am sending an argument to this file but I don't want them to show in the URL I.E. when the above path is in the browser the actual rule should be:

```
www.domain.com/test.php?state=yes
```

What should be the .htaccess rule for this?
Currently i have in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ /test.php?view=index [NC,L]
```

But this is throwing a 500 server error???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get a 500 error, what else do you have in your .htaccess?

Here's what you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test\.php test.php?view=index [NC,L,QSA]
```

The QSA flag was missing:

When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

Consider the following rule:

```
RewriteRule /pages/(.+) /page.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

With the [QSA] flag, a request for `/pages/123?one=two` will be mapped to `/page.php?page=123&one=two`. Without the [QSA] flag, that same request will be mapped to `/page.php?page=123` - that is, the existing query string will be discarded.

source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa